# jquery selection in context of a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an on the fly (not part of the DOM document), HTML code. Something like-

```
<div class="media"> 
abc
</div>
<div class="media"> 
efg
</div>  
<div class="nvid">
   <div class="media">
qwr
   </div>    
</div>
```

now i make a jQuery obj for the above html using,

```
jq = jQuery(above html);
```

then i select the divs having class as 'media' by using the syntax-

```
jQuery('div.media', jq).each(console.log("found"));
```

now, ideally i should get three 'found' printed on the command line, but i am getting only one. any ideas, what i am missing?

Comment: Please use the provided code formatting options to make reading your code easier.

Comment: -1 I've done it, but I suspect its not what you want. Please revisit your question and format it correctly.

Comment: Straight from the help box to your right: *indent code by 4 spaces*

Comment: sorry for the formatting, posted in a hurry.

Comment: print out your jq object, see what is in it. the JQuery(above html) html is not in your code, maybe add it, so we can see your markup of that

Comment: the jq object is correct(checked in firebug), it shows all 3 divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** for clarity.

Behind the scenes using the [core jQuery(selector, context)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) will perform a `.find()`. Reading the [docs on .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) it states it will search the current elements' children.

Meaning your call will do the following:

Take `<div class="media">abc</div>`'s children -- 0 children -- and look for `.media` 0 results.

Take `<div class="media">efg</div>`'s children -- 0 children -- and look for `.media` 0 results.

Take `<div class="nvid">qwr</div>`'s children -- 0 children -- and look for `.media` 0 results.

To do it the DOM way, wrap it in a div and do your find:

```
var html = '<div class="media">abc</div>' + 
           '<div class="media">efg</div>' +
           '<div class="nvid">qwr</div>';
var obj = $(html);
//this fails:
$('div.media',obj).each(function(){console.log("found with jquery object");});

// this works as a single DOM object
var wrap = $('<div/>').append(obj).eq(0);
$('div.media',wrap).each(function(){console.log("found with DOM object");});
```

The reason this works is because we insert your html as children, and do the search on the parent container (wrapper) and it gets 3 children, and it matches 2 of those children.

To do it the `filter()` way and return a NEW jquery object with just those elements: [link to filter docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
obj.filter('.media').each(function(){console.log("found with Filter");});
```

Based on your comment you can do something like:

```
$(html).filter('.media').each(function(){
   var myDiv = $(this);
   // do stuff with myDiv.html();
});
```

You can checkout the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGhNf/) - slightly outdated now.

Comment: But what i am not getting is that why is the first solution, which is so obvious, failing in this case?

Comment: i cant use filter. i have to select. see the edited html code. for this, i need to find all 3 divs with class media and then do something with their innerHTML.

Comment: Updated to explain things a bit more and add more links.

Answer (score 3):

You must pass a *function* to `.each`, and you could better code along the lines of this this, because it isn't attached to the DOM:

```
jq.filter(function(){ return $(this).hasClass('media') })
  .each(function() { console.log("found"); });
```

Comment: i cant use filter. i have to select. see the edited html code. for this, i need to find all 3 divs with class media and then do something with their innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the way you call your console.log(). it evaluates right there and shows found even if nothing is found. because you don't pass a reference to a function, you just call log('found')

you should have

```
jQuery('div.media', jq).each(function() { console.log("found") });
```